# How can I vertically center text-only TabBar buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, tabitem

I'm making some **TabView** buttons in **SwiftUI** (**Xcode 11.1**, **Swift 5.1**, and **iOS 13.1.3**).

For my **TabView**, I don't want *any* images -- just text.  This code accomplishes that nicely:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        TabView {
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("My Projects")
            }
            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Augmented Reality")
            }

            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Products")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in this case, the text ends up aligned to the very bottom of the tab bar items, like this:
[image: tab bar with labels at the bottom]

What I want, though is for the tab bar **not** to reserve space for the icons, and to vertically center the text -- something like this mock-up:

[image: tab bar mock-up showing desired layout]

I've tried sticking it in a **VStack** and trying to adjust the alignment, but nothing changes.

Is there some smart way to do this, or do I need to do some sort of offset by a specific number of points?

Also FYI, Apple's [developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) says, "*Tab views only support tab items of type Text, Image, or an image followed by text. Passing any other type of view results in a visible but empty tab item.*"

I should add that I can use **.offset** to adjust the entire **TabView**, but that's obviously not what we want.  **.tabItem** itself ignores any **.offset** given, as does the **Text** within **.tabItem**.

I was able to get closer, by doing this -- essentially I'm moving the content view for each tab down by 40.0 points, and then moving the entire **TabView** up by 40.  This looks much closer, but the background behind the tabs is then messed up:

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let vOffset: CGFloat = 40.0
    var body: some View {


        TabView {
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("My Projects")
            }.offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: vOffset))

            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Augmented Reality")
            }.offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: vOffset))

            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Products")
            }.offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: vOffset))
        }
        .offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -vOffset))
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: TabView and tab content views offset in opposite directions vertically]

I assume it will be possible in some way to fix that background, though haven't quite figured out how yet.

The other thought is that I wonder if it's even a good idea to do this sort of "hacky" thing.  Or if this even ***is*** a hacky thing?  I know the whole idea of the declarative nature of **SwiftUI** is to separate the implementation from the declaration.  With that in mind, it would be conceivable to expect that some future implementation could look very different, and thus be made to look stupid via the hacky offsets I'm doing here.

That aside, I still want to do it, for now anyway.

So for now I'm looking for a way to fix the background color of the tab bar area, and also, of course, a less hacky way to solve the original problem.

Thanks!

Comment: for the background color of the tab bar area, you can use `appearance`.

 `UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green`.

Comment: @KetanOdedra Hm.. Maybe I will resort to that, but was hoping to stay entirely within the SwiftUI world if possible.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Not `Text` is entered (that can be considered as fix for PO)...

[image: demo1]

... but image is always shown to the top of center (independently of there is text or not):

[image: demo2]

[image: demo3]

Answer (score 0):

The empty space is room for an icon. The TabView is not really customizable. You can turn the text into graphics and insert it using Image - that should push it upwards. It won’t be perfectly centered though.

Comment: Right, I know the empty space is for the icon, but I want to not have the empty space.  I can use .offset to adjust the entire TabView, but that's obviously not what we want.  .tabItem itself ignores any .offset given, as does the Text within .tabItem.

Comment: Any styling you place on either Image or Text inside tabItem() is going to get ignored. The only way is to turn your text into a graphic and use Image to place it higher up.

Answer (score -6):

try

```
TabView(alignment: .center ,spacing: 20))
{
Text("The First Tab")
      .tabItem {
           Text("My Projects")
       }
}
```

Comment: TabView has two initializers and neither takes alignment or spacing.